# PowerShell-for each return single line

Tags: powershell, foreach

I created a script for returning Azure vault replicated status for every AzureVM

```
 $items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $Containers
    foreach ($item in $items)
  {
   $a=$item.ReplicationHealth,$item.RecoveryAzureVMName
   write-host $a  
}
```

getting desired output:

```
Normal VM1
Normal VM2
Critical VM3
Normal VM4
Critical VM5
```

I need above output to pass to zabbix.Unfortunately, zabbix can accept only one line in single loop,so i need to modify for loop somehow,to return first line in output, then in second run to return second line and so on

for getting first line (`Normal VM1`) i tried

```
foreach ($item in $items)
{
write-host $item.ReplicationHealth,$item.RecoveryAzureVMName | select -First 1
}
```

but i'm getting all five lines in output, is it possible to put output to array and then to return particular line from it ?

Comment: Please [don't use `Write-Host` to output _results_](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Comment: It makes more sense to monitor each VM and to check them by name/id with a single item than getting all your output and parsing it (which is more complex and a waste of time imho)

Comment: Just posted new answer (with exporting results to file and push it in one go)

Answer (score 1):

By passing items this way you will enumerate them instead of concatenate results.

Try this way:

```
foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $a = '{0} {1}' -f $item.ReplicationHealth,$item.RecoveryAzureVMName
    Write-Host $a  
}
```

Using `-f` operator starts with a format string, followed by one or more objects or expressions that will be converted to strings and inserted at a specified place in the format string.

The `{0}` in the format string is a format item. 0 is the index of the object whose string value will be inserted at that position. (Indexes start at 0.) If the object to be inserted is not a string, its ToString method is called to convert it to one before inserting it in the result string.

Example:

```
'{0} is an {1}' -f 'This','example'
This is an example
```

Comment: thanks,but it doesn't work: i need to get, first line `Normal VM1`, then, in second forloop run to get `Normal VM2` and so on...

Comment: @xerks, the loop will send items one by one this way. It's just that you get all lines together to console though they still separated. Try changing `Write-Host` to `Write-Output` and pass output to zabbix inside foreach on every loop .

Comment: @xerks, I am not familiar with `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem` output, what's `$item` object looks like? Is that a set of objects as well?

Comment: I like you're using `-f`, I keep forgetting about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $Containers
$items | foreach { "$($_.ReplicationHealth) $($_.RecoveryAzureVMName)" }
```

This will return:

```
Normal VM1
Normal VM2
Critical VM3
Normal VM4
Critical VM5
```

If you want only the 1st line, you can pipe it into `select`

```
$items | foreach { "$($_.ReplicationHealth) $($_.RecoveryAzureVMName)" } | select -First 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure it out-kick all output to file and send it in one go:

```
$filename = "C:\trapper.imports";
write-host $filename;

foreach ($item in $items)
{
'"{0}" {1}' -f "VM01",'replication['+$item.RecoveryAzureVMName+']',""""+$item.ReplicationHealth+"""" | Add-Content -LiteralPath $filename -Encoding "Default" -Force;

}

cd "C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\bin\win64"

.\zabbix_sender.exe -z zabbix_host -p 10051 -c "C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\conf\zabbix_agentd.win.conf" -i $filename -vv
```